# How to make SharedPreferences read/write work on non-UI thread?

Tags: android, performance

SharedPreferences read and write operations are by default working on ui thread. How could we make it run in other threads to avoid blocking main thread?

Comment: Post some code and clear your question with more details

Comment: use some handler or broadcast reciever to do this.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferenced are related to context. You can only reference it through a context.

You can simply pass context as a parameter to your class. For example in the constructor.

In your activity do:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

make methods of reading / writing of shared pref `synchronised`  + Pass the `Application Context` to your SharedPref Class.  Hope this helps.